# Scala Collections inconsistencies

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Why is there a lack of consistency between Sets and Lists in Scala Collections API?

For example, there is immutable Set, but also a mutable one. If I want to use the latter, I can simply do this:

```
val set = Set[A]()
set += new A
```

However, there is no mutable List, per se. If I want to write a similar code snippet using Lists, which data structure to use? LinkedList sounds as a good candidate, because it is mutable, but has no += method defined. ListBuffer seems to satisfy the requirements, but it is not a list.

After reading 2.8 Collections docs I come to the conclusion MutableList is probably the best fit.

I still somehow wish there was scala.collection.mutable.List.

Comment: And not mutable.MutableSet? :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason for this is that Java has co-opted the *functional* `List` type to mean something that it is not (i.e. `java.util.List` is not a *list*).

It probably makes no sense for a functional programming language to have a *mutable* `List` as such a type is an oxymoron. Hence `ListBuffer` or `ArrayBuffer`. Or just use `IndexedSeq`, of which there are mutable and immutable implementations

Answer (score 9):

The sequence/list analogue of `Set` in Scala's collection libraries is `Seq`. `List` is just a particular, immutable implementation of `Seq`, as is `Vector`. `ArrayBuffer` or `ListBuffer` are typical implementations of `mutable.Seq`.

Comment: Thanks for the simple clarification -- this has always bothered me.

Answer (score 3):

ArraySeq may be what you are looking for, except += is exceptionally slow.   You could also use a java.util.ArrayList and import collection.JavaConversions._

It seems Scala lacks a good mutable List-like collection with constant time index (like ArrayList for java).

In any case, note that "List" refers to exactly the type "scala.immutable.List".   Therefore Seq (or some other more abstract collection type), is the type you should expect in methods rather than "List" if you want to generalize over immutable/mutable collections.

More ideal is requring an IndexedSeq, which sort of means that the index operation is performant for that collection.   However, I'm not sure ListBuffer falls into that category.

Comment: Scala's "good mutable List-like collection" "like ArrayList for java" is ArrayBuffer.

Comment: ArrayBuffer is great for append but not as good for prepend.  Java's ArrayList will actually try to amortize costs to prepend as well, making it slightly better in my opinion.   Yes ArrayBuffer is probably good enough if you're just appending on to a list and indexing elements.

Comment: Java's ArrayList is no more efficient than Scala's ArrayBuffer when prepending. Both are copying all existing elements on prepend and that takes time linear in the number of stored elements. Maybe you are mixing up ArrayList and ArrayDeque?

Comment: At least in the Harmony implementation, this is not 100% the case.   IF you first remove the head of the ArrayList, the operation performs no copies.   If you then prepend to the list, again there are no copies.   It's not unitl the list has to be resized that it will do so.   For the most part you could probably use ArrayBuffer when you used to use java.util.ArrayList, but I do wish for something with exactly the same semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Because `Set` is just a trait -- it is abstract and requires an implementation. So one can speak of classes which are `mutable.Set` or `immutable.Set`.

Meanwhile, `List` is a class, an implementation of the (abstract) trait `immutable.LinearSeq`. There can never be any other class which is also a `List`. You'll find out, however, that there *is* a `mutable.LinearSeq` trait.

In Java terms, you are comparing interfaces with classes -- they are distinct.

Comment: The distinction in sect. 16.8 of staircase book, global List object (methods do not work on all List objects) vs. List class, is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget `scala.collection.mutable.{LinkedList,DoubleLinkedList}`. They are mutable, and they are `LinearSeq`. Mutation is a little weird--you can modify the head by assigning to the `elem` reference, and the tail by assigning to the `next` reference.

For example, this loop changes all negative values to zero.

```
val lst = collection.mutable.LinkedList(1, -2, 7, -9)
var cur = lst
while (cur != Nil) { 
  if (cur.elem < 0) cur.elem = 0
  cur = cur.next 
}
```

This loop removes every second element from the list.

```
var cur = lst
while (cur != Nil && cur.next != Nil) { 
  cur.next = cur.next.next
  cur = cur.next 
}
```

I am not suggesting that these are any better than the immutable List. I am just pointing out that Scala has mutable lists that look fairly similar to what you have seen in your data structures class.